# How does Fortran convert a real number to Integer

Tags: fortran, fortran77

For example,

```
SUBROUTINE DoSomething (Z,L)                             
  IMPLICIT DOUBLE PRECISION (A-H,O-Z)                               

  D=Z*77.1234567D0                                           
  L=D                                                      

  RETURN                                                         
 END
```

And for talking purposes, let us assume D is equal to **-1.5**, would in this case L be equals to **-1 or -2.** In other words, does it round up or round down?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am reading a vintage code and I have no means of compiling it. The best I can do is use an online compiler but I believe that uses Fortran 95 I think. I just want to be sure, so maybe someone can chime in.

Comment: Fortran will simply discard the fractional part of the number, so `-3.7` becomes `-3`, `0.4` becomes `0`, `1.25` becomes `1` and so forth.

Comment: Unless this is a one time thing, you really ought to just go download a free compiler.

Comment: Thank you. I needed to be sure because I am converting the code to a different language and it handles it different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Conversion to an integer type for assignment follows use of the intrinsic function `int`.  The effect is defined as (F2008 13.7.81)

> If A is of type real, there are two cases: if|A|<1, INT(A) has the value 0; if |A| ≥1, INT(A) is the integer whose magnitude is the largest integer that does not exceed the magnitude of A and whose sign is the same as the sign of A.

In this case, then, `L` will take the value `-1`.

Answer (score 2):

Either use `NINT()` which is the nearest integer, or `INT()`. `INT()` only returns the signed integer part of a number. `NINT()` works as follows:

> If a is greater than zero, NINT(a) has the value INT(a+ 0.5); if a is less than or equal to zero, NINT(a) has the value INT(a- 0.5).

Specifically `NINT(0.5d0) = 1`